# Why can't I load the Artorias of the Abyss DLC?

Tags: xbox-360, dark-souls

When I try to load the game, along with the Artorias of the Abyss DLC, to play offline, I receive an error stating the DLC failed to load properly and that I will not have access to that content or to my characters who have DLC equipment. However, when I load the game and DLC to play online, it works perfectly. Can this DLC only be played online, or is something wrong?

Comment: Your question contains the correct answer. Many games do this with DLC, most notably Bethesda's Elder Scrolls games Oblivion and Skyrim. I know that there are others but am unable to remember which.

Comment: I have the DLC for dark souls and I can Play online and offline with all the perks of the DLC though I am unsure of why they would fail in your scenario plus I'm playing PS3. @Ravekner I am unsure of what you mean by the DLCs failing for Oblivion and skyrim as these games are exclusively offline games? or do you mean failing in general after download?

Comment: @user44721 I would try reinstalling the DLC I'm unsure if this will work but make sure you have a stable connection and the download is not interrupted then try running it again

Comment: @Nathan Taylor Xbox requires you to have an internet connection to access DLC for any game regardless of whether or not it is a single player offline game or multiplayer online game. I don't believe that you need to be a gold member but that may be a possibility as well.

Comment: @Ravekner ahh I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

Whatever Xbox you downloaded the content to first is the Xbox that it is licensed to and should be able to be used online or offline from anyone who uses the Xbox locally. If you have downloaded the content to a different Xbox first, this is why. To fix this, try deleting the content and redownloading it. If that doesn't work, you will have to re-license the content from the Xbox or the link on [Xbox.com](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/downloadable-content/download-content?icid=furl_home)

Enjoy.

Answer (score -4):

Microsoft requires anyone using a Xbox360 to have internet in order to access DLC for a game whether it has online features or not.

If you do not have access to an internet connection, the DLC will become unavailable for use and all save files that have utilized the DLC will become unplayable until you have access to the internet again.

Unfortunately this is the system Microsoft implemented to prevent people from sharing DLC across multiple consoles, but it affects the owner in the same way, no internet, no DLC.

Comment: I'm not sure if your answer is Xbox One specific but this is extremely untrue for the 360. I use DLC offline on a daily basis.

Comment: @mondrianaire have you unplugged your xbox360 from its power source after disconnecting it from the internet, I used to take my xbox with me on trips and most of the time I wouldn't have access to internet, so I couldn't use my DLC.

Comment: I routinely put my profile and my dlc on a usb stick, bring it to a local coffee shop with a 360 without internet access, and play DLC there. It may be that the game has to be fully patched, but not necessarily connected to the internet.